# Explicit insert or Default constraint

Tags: sql-server

Is it better to insert a value all the time for a column (create time, update time) or to put a default constraint to now(). How bad is default constraint when compared to explicit insert. I mean is there any performance overhead with default. Also is a constraint as bad as a trigger?

Comment: Is something stopping you from testing scenarios specific to your workload?

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that. Was part of a discussion where someone supported explicit insert (in turn depending on an external app to insert data) but I could not agree on that. I would say a constraint any day. Just wanted a public view.

Comment: Your question could use some more information then. The data type(s) being inserted, how many rows are being inserted at a time, and anything you've tried to test things so far.

Comment: Let's take the data type as datetime and data insertion can be as low as one row at a time and around 5 rows at a time on an average. I understand that it wouldn't make much of difference with such fewer data but it's about having a general view of database table design.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 4):

> How bad is default constraint when compared to explicit insert.

It will be the difference between a system function execution to get the date versus the overhead to pass the explicit value through the call chain. In my opinion, not significant.

Bugs could be introduced either way. With the explicit value, a programmer *will*, eventually, forget to populate the parameter and the SQL will fail at run-time. Making the column NOT NULL hides the error further and requires thorough checking on top of thorough testing. It is difficult to enforce sensible, system-enforced checks on the provided value without invoking other system functions or hard-coding values and making the system brittle

With a default, the value used is that at the server at the instant of execution. Time zones can play havoc here, especially if the client and server are in different zones. Writing and immediately reading a value can, in theory, produce any result from twenty six hours in the future or past. This is not intuitive. If the server observes daylight saving values may be duplicated, or be in the future immediately after the autumn step backwards.  If the value is business-significant (say, the payment date on an invoice) and the user is supposed to enter an historical date (when the invoice was received), but the application fails to send it (a bug) the server will default the current date. That could have big legal and financial implications for the business.

To me these approaches have different semantics. Application-provided values hold meaning from the business and user. System-defaulted values have a context internal to the database, data lineage and maintenance. They do not encode business-meaningful information. Use each as needed. The performance differences are negligible but the confusion could be immense.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, no. There's no discernible difference.

Feel free to alter this test harness to suit your needs.

```
USE tempdb;
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #explicit, #constraint, #logger;

CREATE TABLE #explicit (id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, crap DATETIME);

CREATE TABLE #constraint (id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, crap DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE());

CREATE TABLE #logger (id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, pattern NVARCHAR(100), StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME, TimeDiff AS (DATEDIFF(MS, StartTime, EndTime)));

DECLARE @sql_explicit NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @sql_constraint NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @counter INT = 0;
DECLARE @row_number INT = 0;
DECLARE @nl NCHAR(4) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(13);

INSERT #logger (pattern, StartTime)
VALUES ( N'Explicit Insert', GETDATE() );

    WHILE @counter <= 100000

    BEGIN

        SELECT @row_number = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5) + 1;

        SET @sql_explicit = REPLICATE(' INSERT #explicit (crap ) VALUES (GETDATE()) ' + @nl, @row_number);

        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql_explicit;

        SET @counter += 1;

        IF @counter % 10000 = 0 BEGIN RAISERROR('Explicit Iteration: %d', 0, 1,  @counter) WITH NOWAIT; END;

    END;

UPDATE #logger 
SET EndTime = GETDATE()
WHERE pattern = N'Explicit Insert';

SET @counter = 0;

INSERT #logger (pattern, StartTime)
VALUES ( N'Constraint Insert', GETDATE() );

    WHILE @counter <= 100000

    BEGIN

        SELECT @row_number = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5) + 1;

        SET @sql_constraint = REPLICATE(' INSERT #constraint (crap ) DEFAULT VALUES  ' + @nl, @row_number);

        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql_constraint;

        SET @counter += 1;

        IF @counter % 10000 = 0 BEGIN RAISERROR('Constraint Iteration: %d', 0, 1,  @counter) WITH NOWAIT; END;

    END;

UPDATE #logger 
SET EndTime = GETDATE()
WHERE pattern = N'Constraint Insert';


SELECT *
FROM #logger AS l;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Records]
FROM #explicit AS e;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Records]
FROM #constraint AS c;
```